# How to scroll Firemonkey TListBox without capturing focus in its controls?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, gesture, delphi-10-seattle

I have a `TListBox` with controls in each item, such as `TEdit`, `TComboBox`, `TSwitch`, etc, aligned to the right. There are about 20 items in this list, so it extends beyond the screen, and thus user needs to scroll (by sliding finger) to get to the bottom.

The problem is that even in a quick gesture, if user swipes their finger initially on one of these controls, that control takes focus and the list doesn't scroll. Currently, the only way to scroll up or down is to swipe the finger on the left side of the list, where there aren't any controls. I *could* disable `HitTest` or `CanFocus`, but then that control would *never* get focus, even when the user wants to actually tap on it.

How can I allow user to swipe up or down on these controls to scroll the list *without* that control taking focus?

Comment: Are you using Tokyo with the hotfix or a previous version?

Comment: @AlbertoMiola I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Are you suggesting this was fixed in the Tokyo hotfix?

Comment: I was gonna post an answer but I tested and it didn't really work. I had your same issue long time ago but I really wasn't able to solve the problem. I've just disabled the CanFocus :( not really a solution...

Comment: I haven't tested if it works, but maybe a possible solution would be an edit of the custom style of the component. I thought about this but at the end I had just opted for CanFocus = false. This is something I don't really like too, but I guess that unless a "hard edit" (editing the style) we can't do much!

Comment: Do you use `TVertScrollBox`?

Comment: @Victoria No, I'm hoping I don't have to because of cross-platform styling. I need to match the target device.

Comment: 3 years later, this problem still persists. Has anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

To solve that insted using a TListBox I used a TVertScrollBox with a layout inside.

Each control is align to top and, to make it work, I needed a VKVertScrollBox from:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/VKVertScrollbox

Doing so you will have a scrollable list of components where you can swipe your finger down and see it moving.

Besides, to avoid the entering and getFocus on each component when swiping you can use a helper on each component to catch the movement by overriding MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp and prevent entering overriding doEnter (also overrited) if it is moving (catched on MouseMove method).